# How to find the date using internet (ie ntp) from bash?

Tags: bash, ntp

How can I learn date and time from the internet using bash without installing anything extra.

I am basically looking for an equivalent of bash $ date, but using an NTP (or any other way) to get the correct date and time from the internet. All the methods I find (such as ntpd) are meant to correct the system time, which is not my purpose.

Comment: `ntpdate -q <ntp server>` - queries server without setting

Comment: @MichaelO. I am new to this and I don't know how to get a usable output from this: (I mean how can I get only the date or secs since epoc from this):desktop user$ ntpdate -q pool.ntp.org           
server 129.250.35.250, stratum 2, offset -0.010905, delay 0.12845
server 144.76.3.142, stratum 2, offset -0.010141, delay 0.12025
server 131.234.137.63, stratum 2, offset -0.012191, delay 0.12454
server 37.58.57.238, stratum 2, offset -0.014898, delay 0.12166
29 Jul 19:35:48 ntpdate[66809]: adjust time server 144.76.3.142 offset -0.010141 sec'

Comment: `ntpdate -q pool.ntp.org |grep -o "^.*:..:.."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`date` has a lot of options for formatting, but I'm assuming that you just want the date and time:

```
ntpdate -q time.google.com | sed -n 's/ ntpdate.*//p'
```

(or any other time server)

Answer (score 1):

If you have `ntpd` installed & configured then you can use the NTP Query command `ntpq -crv` which will return;

```
associd=0 status=04ff leap_none, sync_uhf_radio, 15 events, stale_leapsecond_values,
version="ntpd 4.2.6p5@1.2349-o Mon Feb  6 07:22:46 UTC 2017 (1)",
processor="x86_64", system="Linux/4.10.13-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64", leap=00,
stratum=1, precision=-23, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=1.000, refid=PPS,
reftime=dd2c9f10.f25911ee  Wed, Aug  2 2017 19:57:20.946,
clock=dd2c9f11.f4251b0a  Wed, Aug  2 2017 19:57:21.953, peer=6516, tc=4,
mintc=3, offset=-0.005, frequency=-17.045, sys_jitter=0.110,
clk_jitter=0.007, clk_wander=0.003, tai=37, leapsec=201701010000,
expire=201706010000
```

You want the line starting `clock` which gives the time, date etc - you would be best parsing this out with `awk` or something if you just want the date stamp rather then everything else.

You do *not* need to be a root user to run the command. It won't set anything, but will query your local server (presuming your running ntp) and present the details.